# Jenkins - Active Choice Reactive Reference

Tags: jenkins

I am using Active Choices Plugin to dinamically load parameters. I want to read last line of a $workspace file as a parameter.

In this example, when selecting "pedro" username it should display linea 1" because is the last line of the document that is in "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Aa.test1.txt"

This is how the job is configured:

[image]

And this is when trying to build the job with parameters: 
[image]

If I execute it in Jenkins Script console it displays the output correctly...
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got the idea wrong. You're using Reactive parameter for "username" but forgetting to specify which parameter to react to. See empty "Referenced parameters" text field in "username" parameter definition.
The logic is pretty simple. When your "referenced parameter" has changed it makes Reactive choice to rebuild dependent parameter (username) and show the value according to the logic implemented as Groovy script.

Comment: Excellent!  I've been struggling to figure this out, and couldn't find out why my parameters were not working anywhere else until I read your answer. Kudos!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "choice parameter" you should use "Active choice parameter" and use the name as a referenced parameter in "Active choice Reactive parameter" and finally you can use the name given for "Active choice reactive parameter" as a referenced parameter in "Active choice Reactive Reference parameter".